# Is possible compress and uncompress a file with a password but considering an expiration date too?

Tags: security, tar, password, zip, compression

In Linux about compression files can be accomplished with the `tar` and `zip/unzip` commands, perhaps more. I know that is possible establish a password protection for security reasons.

The **question** is:

- Is possible compress and uncompress a file with a password **but** considering a expiration date too?

For example:

- Is created some information in the *omicron* directory
- It is compressed with the *abc* password and it expires in an specific date - established manually for example using the `--pwd-expire-date 05/05/2023` option (of course, if it is possible)

**Situation**

The compressed file is shared to Person1 and Person2 - now, *even if Person3 gets the file for any reason* - if he gets/breaks the password but it happens at 05/06/2023 (one day later), it **can't be uncompressed** *due the expiration date*.

Is possible accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot encrypt files using tar, use tar+gpg if you want to do so.
2. You can encrypt files using zip, but it won't keep track of file attributes (such as ownership, permissions, etc.), depending on what you want to compress, zip might no be suitable.
3. You cannot set an expiration date on something you encrypt, you have the key to decrypt it or not, there's no such thing as "this secret key is not valid anymore". Encryption is a "static" process, you cannot control access to the cipher if the other party has the key to decrypt it.
4. Certificates do have expiration dates, but that's for signature verification purposes only, not encryption. Plus, it is up to the client to consider that expiration or not.
5. What you could do as a workaround is to upload an encrypted archive somewhere (like [swisstransfer](https://www.swisstransfer.com)), and set an expiration date at which it won't be possible anymore to download the file

Comment: Regarding point 2, Info-Zip does store Unix file attributes. Point 5 has the caveat that any copy downloaded before the expiry date will remain valid afterwards.

Comment: It seems the best approach is put the access control in some server and use as usual the password.

Comment: @ManuelJordan yes exactly. I mentioned swisstransfer as an example, but if you have your own server, that's even better ! Note however that as StephenKitt Mentioned, the archive will remain usable after it's downloaded. There's nothing you can do about it.